# Use string formatting for a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists and I need to print it using string formatting. If there is an 'x' in the list, I need it to display a '*'.

I need to also calculate counted and uncounted items, what I've got isn't working correctly. See output for clarification.

```py
list = [
['animal', 'cat', 2017, 'x'],
['cutlery', 'fork', 2007, 'o'],
['furniture', 'chair', 2019, 'x']
]
```

To add the index numbers to the items, I used enumerate, works good.
To format, I used string formatting, works good.
Part I'm stuck on is I need to convert 'x' to '*' and 'o' to ' ' and how to display the counted and uncounted items.

Code I have so far:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    print('{}. {} {} - {} ({})'.format(index, item[3], item[0], item[1], item[2]))
counted_items = list[4].count("x")
uncounted_items = list[4].count("o")
print("{} items counted, {} items still to count".format(counted_items, uncounted_items))
```

```
Current output with error:
0. x cat - 2017 (animal)
1. 0 fork - 2007 (cutlery)
2. x chair - 2019 (furniture)
Traceback (most recent call last):
counted_items = list[3].count("x")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
What output should look like:
0. * cat - 2017 (animal)
1.   fork - 2007 (cutlery)
2. * chair - 2019 (furniture)
2 items counted, 1 item too count
```

where '*' equals counted

Comment: You don't seem to have attempted that at all, why did you expect your current code to show that?

Comment: I have added code for count and uncounted too, check it if it is helpful for you :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was still working on it while you answered and I managed to find some of what I was looking for and edited the question.

Comment: @amrs-tech thank you for your help, I seem to have come up with the same solution for the formatting which is good

Comment: list[4] sure gives error because you have only three items in `list`, I think for counting you can refer edited solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you needed.

```
list = [
['animal', 'cat', 2017, 'x'],
['cutlery', 'fork', 2007, 'o'],
['furniture', 'chair', 2019, 'x'],
]
c1 = c2 = 0
for index, item in enumerate(list):
  if item[3] == 'x':
    item[3] = '*'
    c1 += 1
  if item[3] == 'o':
    item[3] = ' '   
    c2 += 1
  print('{}. {} {} - {} ({})'.format(index, item[3], item[0], item[1], item[2]))

print(c1,' item(s) counted, and ',c2,' item(s) uncounted!')
```

I've tested it. Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks heap! Helped me out a lot

Comment: I'm happy that it helped :)